# Can't get the second SQLite database column into TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I just want to print out my two column database but only one column is being displayed in the TextView. The first column is the user input and the second column is the date of the user input. I'm pretty sure the problem is either in the second while loop in the databaseToString() method in the MyDBHandler.java class or in my getters and setters in the Product.java class.

MyDBHandler.java

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String KICK_TABLE = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME_DATE = "productnamedate";

//We need to pass database information along to superclass
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

/*
CREATE TABLE table_name (
        column_1 data_type,
        column_2 data_type,
        column_3 data_type
);
*/

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " +
            KICK_TABLE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME_DATE + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + KICK_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Product product){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
    db.insert(KICK_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addProductDate(Product productdate){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME_DATE, productdate.get_productnamedate());
    db.insert(KICK_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + KICK_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
}

public Integer dbSize(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCount = db.rawQuery("SELECT count(" + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + ") FROM " + KICK_TABLE, null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    int count = mCount.getInt(0);

    mCount.close();
    return count;
}

public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + KICK_TABLE + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    //this is the sql date attempt
    c.getColumnIndex("productnamedate");
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productnamedate")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productnamedate"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
        }

    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product {

private int _id;
private String _productname;
private String _productnamedate;

public Product(){
}

public Product(String productname){
    this._productname = productname;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_productname(String _productname) {
    this._productname = _productname;
}

public void set_productnamedate(String _productnamedate) {
    this._productnamedate = _productnamedate;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String get_productname() {
    return _productname;
}
public String get_productnamedate() {
    return _productnamedate;
}
```

}

KickCounter.java

```
public class KickCounter extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public KickCounter() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment KickCounter.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static KickCounter newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    KickCounter fragment = new KickCounter();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

//SQLite
//Add a product to the database
/*public void addButtonClicked(View view){
    Product product = new Product(kickString);
    dbHandler.addProduct(product);
    printDatabase();
}*/

Button kickButton;
Button removeKickButton;
Button startButton;
Chronometer chronometer;
TextView kickCount;
Integer kick = 0;
//SQLite

TextView sQLiteOutput;

//SQLite
MyDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kick_counter, container, false);

    kickButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.kick_button_ID);
    kickButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    removeKickButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.remove_kick_button_ID);
    removeKickButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    startButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.start_button_ID);
    chronometer = (Chronometer)rootView.findViewById(R.id.chronometer_ID);
    kickCount = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.kickCount_ID);
    sQLiteOutput = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.SQLiteOutput_ID);

    //SQLite
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getContext(), null, null, 1);
   // printDatabase();

    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
    sQLiteOutput.setText(dbString);


    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            kickButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            removeKickButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //trying to make SQL date work here
            String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());

            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();

            chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                            if( chronometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("00:05")) {
                                Snackbar.make(getView(),"Your text",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                end();
                            }
                            if(kick == 10) {
                                Snackbar.make(getView(),"heo",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                                end();
                            }

                        }
            });

        }
    });

    kickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(kick < 10){
                kick++;
                setKickCountText();
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    removeKickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(kick != 0){
                kick--;
                setKickCountText();
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

public void end(){
    chronometer.stop();
    kickButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    removeKickButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    String kickString = kick.toString();
    String dateString = "hello";//new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());


    Product product = new Product(kickString);
    Product productDate = new Product(dateString);

    dbHandler.addProduct(product);
    dbHandler.addProductDate(productDate);

    printDatabase();
}



//SQLite
//Print the database
public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
    sQLiteOutput.setText(dbString);
    //buckysInput.setText("");
}

public void setKickCountText(){
    kickCount.setText(kick.toString());
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Comment: Q: Have you considered stepping through the debugger?

Comment: In `databaseToString` you should get the values of both fields within `one` while loop.  **But** I am also guessing that when you insert data, you are not actually inserting the `productnamedate` data with the `productname` data - they should be `one` row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually inserting two different rows, instead of one:

```java
dbHandler.addProduct(product);
dbHandler.addProductDate(productDate);
```

Every time you inserting data into the table, you inserting two different rows:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Id | product_name | product_date            |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1 | SOME_NAME    |  null                   |
-----------------------------------------------
|  2 | null         |  SOME_DATE              |
-----------------------------------------------
```

To solve this, make 1 insert method instead of 2:

```java
//Add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Product product, Product productdate){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME_DATE, productdate.get_productnamedate());
    db.insert(KICK_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: I think he needs to sort out his retrieval as well